# Any SymmetricDS replacement framework?

Tags: symmetricds

We were using symmetric DS for database replication, but we are checking if there's any other tool or framework which can do the same thing. We want application level database replication, not db level, because db level need do a lot manual configurations.

Comment: It sounds like you are using the opensource version of SymmetricDS. There is a Professional version that makes the replication configurable via web application. Since you are already running the open source core, you could stand up the Professional instance easily with the existing configuration. You can demo the Pro version for free at http://www.jumpmind.com.

Comment: or automate the creation of SQL configuration by having it described in an excel document, for example, and then build a script which will export to insert/update SQL statements